# C2106 Error in Simple Math Program

Tags: c++, math

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = (1024^3)-(639^3)-(385^3);
    short max = 0;
    cout<< " Prints 0 if no answer." << endl;

    for(int iii = 100; iii < 1000; iii++)
    {
        if(a % iii = 0)
        {
            max = iii;
        }
    }
    cout<< " " << max;

    cin.clear(); cin.ignore(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Just trying to write a simple program so I don't have to calculate and the compiler returns a C2106 error for line 14.

Comment: I doubt the compiler only says "C2106 error for line 14". Please provide the **complete** error message, and also add a comment in your code to indicate where is line 14 so we don't have to count.

Comment: did you intend to use caret (^) as a exponentiation operator? i don't think it works this way in c++

Answer (score 3):

```
if (a % iii = 0)
```

This is an invalid assignment. If you meant to compare, use the comparison operator `==`.

```
if (a % iii == 0)
```

Moreover, exponentiation is not done with `^` in C++. That is actually the bitwise `xor` operator. To do exponentation, use `std::pow` from the `<cmath>` header.

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int a = std::pow(1024, 3) - std::pow(639, 3) - std::pow(385, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be == for comparision

```
       if((a % iii) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`:

```
if(a % iii = 0)
```

This should be:

```
if( a % iii == 0)
```

The result of `a % iii` is a temporary and and in the original code you are trying to assign `0` to that temporary. Besides that error it looks like you are trying to raise some numbers by a power here:

```
int a = (1024^3)-(639^3)-(385^3);
```

the `^` operator is actually bitwise `xor` what you need is [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) from the `cmath` header:

```
int a = std::pow(1024,3)-std::pow(639,3)-std::pow(385,3);
```

I would also avoid [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).